# Create a NetCDF file from Excel for wind speed and direction in R Studio

Tags: qgis, python, r, netcdf

I have an Excel spreadsheet of wind data that contains the wind speed and direction recorded at 5-minute intervals.

I would like to create a NetCDF file for this data so the wind vector data can be mapped in QGIS and to create an animation using QGIS. This is to apply this QGIS lesson [wind-vector-mapping-and-animation-in-Qgis](https://opengislab.com/blog/2020/10/10/wind-vector-mapping-and-animation-in-qgis) for my own case study. I am unsure where to start as I am unfamiliar with the ncdf4 package, but have tried following along with this R studio tutorial on this page: https://pjbartlein.github.io/REarthSysSci/netCDF.html#create-and-write-a-netcdf-file

I am struggling in particular with the defining of dimensions and variables. This was the code I have written so far:

```
  library(ncdf4)
    library(readxl)
    setwd("E:/Geographic Information System/Lake Tarawera/wind_data")
#set path and filename
# Step 1: Read wind data from Excel file
 wind_data <- read_excel("wind_data.xlsx")  # Assuming "wind_data.xlsx" is your file name
 # Open the NetCDF file for writing
 nc <- nc_open("wind_data.nc", write=TRUE)
 # Step 2: Define variables
 direction_var <- ncvar_def("WindDirection", units="degrees", dim='time', longname="Wind Direction", )
    speed_var <- ncvar_def("speed", "double", , units="m/s dim='time', longname="Wind Speed"")

# Step 3: Create a new NetCDF file
nc <- nc_create("wind_data.nc", vars = list(direction_var, speed_var))

# Write direction data
ncvar_put(nc, "direction", wind_data$direction, start=c(1), count=c(length(wind_data$direction)))
# Write speed data
ncvar_put(nc, "speed", wind_data$speed, start=c(1), count=c(length(wind_data$speed)))

# Step 3: Define dimensions
ncdim_def(nc, "time", unlim=TRUE)  # Assuming time is the dimension for your wind data

# Step 5: Write wind data to NetCDF file
ncvar_put(nc, "direction", wind_data$direction, start=c(1), count=c(length(wind_data$direction)))
ncvar_put(nc, "speed", wind_data$speed, start=c(1), count=c(length(wind_data$speed)))

# Step 6: Close the file
nc_close(nc)
```

These are the columns and first 11 rows of the spreadsheet:

```
DateTime        WndSpeed    WindDirection
6/05/2021 16:45 3.498912    221.600006
6/05/2021 16:50 2.91576     212.299988
6/05/2021 16:55 0.97192     209.600006
6/05/2021 17:00 0.388768    188.199982
6/05/2021 17:05 0.583152    200
6/05/2021 17:10 2.332608    194
6/05/2021 17:15 1.166304    194.899994
6/05/2021 17:20 0.777536    165.600006
6/05/2021 17:25 0.583152    98
6/05/2021 17:30 0.388768    78.199997
```